# Google Swiffy, and responsive design, height

Tags: html, flash, actionscript, responsive-design, google-swiffy

I'm testing out Swiffy, and plugging it into Zurb's Foundation responsive framework. It all works well. I also updated the CSS for the `#swiffycontainer` container to have a width of `width: 100%;`.

The content fits nicely into the grid, but the my only issue is that if the size isn't set explicitly, then on a smaller screen, then, I get this issue with the height being way way larger than the content, even with height set at `500px`. This also results in the Swiffy container showing contents *outside* of the *stage*.

Any ideas as to why? Would it be with the SVG generated from Swiffy? Thanks!

**Update:** It seems that this is probably related to AS 2/3's stageScale property on the Stage. Would anybody happen to know of a happy medium between "showAll/SHOW_ALL", and "noBorder/NO_BORDER"? Where the stage still resizes but doesn't show a border around it?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up solving this issue with a bit of CSS that ensures that the *height* is scaled proportionally to the *width* (what ever width it maybe due to the responsive grid). This keeps the flash/Swiffy container from creating the letterbox bars.

In the SWF: Keep the default (AS2):

```
Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
```

In the CSS, created a wrapper on the Swiffy container:

```
.swiffy-wrap { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
}
```

On the Swiffy container

```
#swiffycontainer {
  width : 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: what about as3 for Stage.scaleMode

Answer (score 2):

just put in the html result of swiffy conversion width `100%` be careful only width not height, height, like this

```
div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"
```

works for me